# Websites to check my work?

Tags: calculus

I am in a Calculus I class and have a series of homework problems to do for each chapter like any math class. The interesting point is that the homework is due on the day of the exam. So it becomes a pointless thing if i can't be sure what I am doing is correct, otherwise its just studying something that is wrong.

Is there a Math site or similar that I could potentially upload the questions and answers to see if i am right or wrong? I would rather have it be just flagged incorrect with maybe small input but I don't want the work done for me otherwise I would probably still be screwed on the exam.

I also wouldnt want to upload each question here with my answer saying Check my work as that would be mundane and I dont would think that would be effective or the goal for this site, if i am wrong then i would gladly upload the questions here.

Comment: Wolfram ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Regarding if it's ok to post here, you should search http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ for similar discussions. If you don't find the answer there, post this question there instead. My guess would be that the community thinks it ok as long as you stick to the posting guidelines for homework questions.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks @DanielR

Comment: going to see your teacher is not a possibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was a student, I would do a literary survey for solutions to homework problems, after I had done them.  The problems your professors assign come from somewhere, after all.  Getting a good grounding on the classic books for the field is valuable, at least if you will continue to pursue mathematics.  Also, it will help shape your expository style.  Some texts will repel you and others will attract, based on their style.

Once you have a good idea if you're getting some problems right, you'll have a good idea if you're getting them all right.  In other words, once you understand the basic techniques, you'll find "patterns" that your correct solutions will follow and incorrect solutions will not follow.

Related to this idea, at least at the level of Calculus I, you should not be finding "weird" numbers in your solutions.  $e$, $\pi$, $0$, $1$ will be common scalars.  The numbers $1$ to, say, $3$ will be common as powers of polynomials.  But if you find a $573$ as a power or scalar, you probably took the wrong track somewhere along the line.  Try to find where, and you will have learned a new skill -- how to check your own work when you suspect it is wrong.

If I didn't find a solution, I would post a question (showing all my work and where I was getting stuck and what I think should be going on, etc) on the sci.math newsgroup (Hi everybody!).  math.stackexchange.com seems to be the modern day equivalent (and is probably better since the cranks stayed behind).  Just remember that the more work you do on the problem, the more you will get out of it.  And that people will be more likely to help if you are upfront about it being homework, and you show your work and ask questions based on what you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for the words of encouragement, I grew up with holes in my math because of jumping around schools and so somethings get hard because of them, and otherwise things are easy. I have been studying via classes and Khanacademy.org and other references. Thanks again. and will post when i have any issues with a question. Thanks!